# Product of $n$ positive integers with at most $n-1$ prime divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Below is the question I am having difficulties with:

Show: If the $\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i$ has strictly less than $n$ distinct prime divisors, then there is an $I \subseteq \lbrace 1,...n\rbrace$ s.t. $\prod_{i \in I} a_i$ is a perfect square.

The simplest case I already did:

Consider the simplest case, where $\forall i \in \lbrace 1,...n\rbrace: a_i = p_i \in \mathbb{P}$.

Then by the Pigeon Hole principle $\exists (i,j) \in \lbrace 1,...n\rbrace^2: a_i=p_i=p_j=a_j$.

Now we can simply chose $I = \lbrace i,j \rbrace$ such that $\prod_{i \in I} a_i = p_i^2 = p_j^2$ which is a perfect square.

For the general case, I find it difficult to formally show that the statement is true. The following is my attempt so far:

Let $a_i=\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} p_{j}^{\alpha _{j _{i}}}$ where $\alpha _{j _{i}} \geq 0$. Then

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} p_{j}^{\alpha _{j _{i}}} = \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} \prod_{i=1}^{n}  p_{j}^{\alpha _{j _{i}}} = \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} p_{j}^{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha _{j _{i}}}$$

where there exists at least one $j$ s.t $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha _{j _{i}} \geq 2$$

However, from this point, I don't really see how I can apply the Pigeon Hole principle. Would really appreciate some insight here.

Thanks folks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the bare outlines of a proof. It does not use the pigeonhole principle, as I don't see how that applies to this problem.

The proof hinges on the fact that in a $k$-dimensional vector space, with $k<n$, any set of $n$ vectors will be linearly dependent.

Suppose there are $k<n$ prime divisors of the $a_i$. Each $a_i$ can be uniquely written as a product of prime powers using those $k$ primes (unused primes have exponent $0$ of course). This corresponds to a vector in $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$, the k-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the integers mod $2$, simply by taking as the vector's coordinates those prime exponents modulo $2$.

To turn this into a proof you will have to justify why the vector space does what you want, i.e. establish the homomorphism and show that a linearly dependent set of vectors gives you the set $I$ that you are looking for.

Edit: As the other answer shows, it is possible to prove it using the pigeonhole principle, using the possible sets $I$ as the pigeons, and the elements of the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$ as the pigeonholes.

Comment: "The proof hinges on the fact that in a k-dimensional vector space, with k<n, any set of n vectors will be linearly dependent." Isn't there a pigeonhole principle hiding somewhere in there?

Comment: @Dosidis I don't think so. I agree that it looks a bit like it. In the simplified case that the OP proves where each vector has only one non-zero coordinate then it is indeed the pigeonhole principle. But in the general case I don't think it is related, expecially when using fields other than $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I was referring to the special case, but even in general, you usually establish bases with some form of the well-ordering principle, which is related to the pigeonhole principle. Depending on the way you set up your axioms, it may even be possible to build everything using the pigeonhole. In any case, I was only commending to point out the connection of your argument with OP's original idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof using Pigeonhole Principle (although my explanation is quite bad). Any critique is much appreciated.

Let $n  \geq 2$. $\forall \ I \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}, $ write $\prod_{i \in I} a_i$ in the form $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}, k \leq n-1, \alpha_i \geq 0. $

For each $I$, consider the induced $k$-tuple $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_k)$ modulo $2$. There are at most $2^{n-1}$ distinct such tuples (Each $\alpha_i$ is $0$ or $1$ modulo $2$). Additionally, there are $2^n-1$ subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, excluding the null set.

Since $2^n-1 > 2^{n-1}, $ by the Pigeonhole Principle, there are $2$ distinct subsets, $I_1$ and $I_2$, of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, such that $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_k) = (\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_k)$ modulo $2$. We now consider $2$ cases :

Case $1$: $I_1$ and $I_2$ are disjoint. Clearly, $\prod_{i \in {I_1 \cup I_2}} a_i =p_1^{\alpha_1+\beta_1}p_2^{\alpha_2+\beta_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k+\beta_k}$ is a perfect square, since each exponent $\alpha_{i} + \beta_{i}$ is even.

Case $2$: $I_1$ and $I_2$ are not disjoint, but $I_1$ is not a subset of $I_2$, and vice versa. Let $m$ be a common element, and consider the $2$ new sets $J_1=I_1\setminus \{m\},J_2=I_2\setminus \{m\}$. Clearly, the $2$ new induced tuples $(\alpha_1^{'},\alpha_2^{'},...,\alpha_k^{'})$ and $(\beta_1^{'},\beta_2^{'},...,\beta_k^{'})$ are still equal modulo $2$. If $J_1$ and $J_2$ are disjoint, we are done by Case $1$. Otherwise, we iterate this process until we end up with $2$ disjoint subsets, then apply Case $1$.

Case $3$: $I_1$ is a (strict) subset of $I_2$, or vice versa. W.L.O.G. let it be the latter. Then, consider $\prod_{i \in {I_1 \setminus I_2}} a_i =p_1^{\alpha_1-\beta_1}p_2^{\alpha_2-\beta_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k-\beta_k}$, which is a perfect square since each exponent is a non-negative even integer.

Comment: The 3 cases can be combined using the exclusive or (XOR) operation on $I_1$ and $I_2$.

Comment: Ah, now I see how the pigeonhole principle applies to this problem.